# How to access a Web application/Farm level property bag via jQuery/Javascript/ClientContext

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, jquery, web-application, property

It it possible to access the Web application/Farm level property bag using jQuery/Javscript/ClientContext? If not, then what are the possible alternatives to access Web Application Farm level property bags using jQuery/Javascript

I will appreciate the code example.

Comment: hard to give you code without knowing what you want to do. Simply pushing property bag values to a web service is probably not a good idea (it can expose sensitive data).

Comment: I want to get only the property value from a Web Application using client script. Security is not important for me.

Comment: I would appreciate any code example of retrieving the Web Application level property using the web service.

Comment: Still unclear about your goal. If you want to access a specific set of items in the bag will lead to a different kind of answer that if you want to return all items in the bag. In the former case, I would create a custom DTO class with your very specific data and a custom wcf service to return this data. In the later, if you are ok with the security and privacy impact, I would create a simple OData like service that wrap the property bag.

Comment: Steve, thank you for your concern. I just to want to access key/value pair in my javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to get the property bags of your web application or farm OFTEN, you could create a custom HttpHandler to create a dynamic javascript file which will load the properties you want. See [my blog post about how to create an httphandler](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/custom-httphandler-in-sharepoint-for-getting-dynamic-javascript-code/). The idea is partly inspired from [loading _spPageContextInfo](http://blog.tedpattison.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=9) If you think it is the way to go, I can tell more.

EDIT: I found this question very interesting and I created [a simple solution which registers a httphandler](https://github.com/mirontoli/sp-lend-id/tree/master/tupsam). When you add this as script in your site you'll get all web properties. The http handler can be altered to suit different purposes. Details are on [my blog](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/web-application-properties-as-json/).

Comment: + 1 I think it could be a good start as long as I will be available to acheive my goal. Please go ahead I'm open to your suggestion

Comment: I would appreciate the implementation with an example.

Comment: I'll try to find some time as soon as possible :)

Comment: Here you have [a solution for getting web application properties](https://github.com/mirontoli/sp-lend-id/tree/master/tupsam). Just extend further.

Comment: Ok, I will test and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this SP WebService](http://spservices.codeplex.com/documentation) to do some of the work, the rest you'll have to use AJAX to do.

I'm not that strong in backend dev. but an example could be something like:

C#

```
public object JSONizedObject;
[WebMethod]  
public static string GetWebAppPropertyBag()
{
    // Logic goes here
    JSONizedObject = new JavascriptSerializer.Serialize(PropertyBag object);
    return JSONizedObject;
}
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: "MyWebService.asmx/GetWebAppPropertyBag",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "json/application; utf-8";
    dataType: "jsonp"
    success: function (xData, jqXHR) {  
        //Handle returned data here
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, responseType, responseText) { 
        //Error handling here 
    }
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: So, I will have to deploy a custom web service?

Comment: @SPGeek Yes. This allows you to easily get the propertybag from your codebehind and then send it back to the clientside without having to perform a postback and lose necessary values/info.

Comment: could you please lay down the development steps?

Answer (score 2):

One thing is for sure that you will not be able to access the WebApplication/Farm scoped property bag from the JavaScript Client Object Model because there are no SPWebApplication or SPFarm objects in it. I think your best bet would be building a custom service as many people here have suggested and then exposing the desired property bag through that service.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your suggestion. If not then I am looking for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can also dynamically generate javascript on the server side and register the function in code... This could be done through a webpart, usercontrol, or application page so it can be used in many situations...

You can build the javascript via a string builder and then register it...

[Check out this example on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx). Hope this helps!