# How to get SpWebApplication level property bag using ClientContext?

Tags: client-object-model, web-application, property

is it possible to get SPWebApplication level property bag using JavaScript ClientContext? Code example will be appreciated.

Fine Regards

Comment: You already have posted this question : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36945/how-to-access-a-web-application-farm-level-property-bag-via-jquery-javascript-cl. While it's true you narrowed the context, you shouln't create a new question for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, you can't access it without having to develop a custom Web Service.